# Editor adds <p>&nbsp</p> on every enter

Tags: 8, wysiwyg

I've got a problem with CKEditor in Drupal 8. I've searched related questions like [CKeditor adds extra <p> tags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/30984/ckeditor-adds-extra-p-tags), but almost all questions are related to Drupal 7.

So, my CKEditor automatically applies a `<p>&nbsp</p>` when I hit enter and don't type anything.

> [image: screenshot]

How can I disable this? I don't want to remove the padding or anything of a `<p>` tag. I need something that checks if the paragraph is empty and then don't display it.

Comment: This is standard ckeditor behavior.  Use shift+enter to inserr breaks instead of paragraphs.

Comment: I know that, but I don't want to do that. I want shift-enter to be the default behaviour. Because when a user accidentally presses enter after writing their article, there must not be another `<p>` tag ...

Comment: A solution for Drupal 7: [WYSIWYG module, br instead of p tags in Drupal 7](https://browse-tutorials.com/snippet/wysiwyg-module-br-instead-p-tags-drupal-7). Although I am pretty sure you can use modify this for D8 as well.

Answer (score 2):

have you tried toggling off the "Convert line breaks into HTML (i.e. `<br> and <p>`)" setting on the text input format?

[image]

Comment: Yesss I did never enabled them =/

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can add your own customized filter in a custom module : as an example, this could look like this to remove empty paragraphs :

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_module\Plugin\Filter;

use Drupal\filter\FilterProcessResult;
use Drupal\filter\Plugin\FilterBase;
use Drupal\filter\Annotation\Filter;
use Drupal\Core\Annotation\Translation;

/**
 * Class FilterEmptyParagraphs
 * @Filter(
 *   id = "filter_empty_paragraphs",
 *   title = @Translation("Filter empty paragraphs"),
 *   description = @Translation("Removes empty paragraphs."),
 *   type = Drupal\filter\Plugin\FilterInterface::TYPE_MARKUP_LANGUAGE,
 * )
 * @package Drupal\your_module\Plugin\Filter
 */
class FilterEmptyParagraphs extends FilterBase
{
    /**
     * Performs the filter processing.
     *
     * @param string $text
     *   The text string to be filtered.
     * @param string $langcode
     *   The language code of the text to be filtered.
     *
     * @return \Drupal\filter\FilterProcessResult
     *   The filtered text, wrapped in a FilterProcessResult object, and possibly
     *   with associated assets, cacheability metadata and placeholders.
     *
     * @see \Drupal\filter\FilterProcessResult
     */
    public function process($text, $langcode)
    {
        $regex = '@<p([^>]*)>\s*\n*\t*(&nbsp;)*\s*\n*\t*</p>@igm';
        $text = preg_replace($regex, '', $text);
        return new FilterProcessResult($text);
    }
}
```

(regex not tested)